# ¿Qué propiedad puedo utlizar en un TextBox como si fuese una propiedad `Text2`?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hice una función de `Placeholder` para los `TextBox`, por defecto en la propiedad `Text` de cada uno escribí algo para identificar el tipo de dato que se le ingresará sin la necesidad de usar `Labels`, Por ejemplo:
`txt1.Text = "Ingresa nombre", txt2.Text = "Ingresa domicilio", txt3.Text = "Ingresa teléfono"`.
Entonces la función que realicé al momentó de que un `TextBox` tenga el `foco`, se borrará lo que tiene en su propiedad `Text` para que el usuario comience a escribir, y en caso de que lo deje en blanco y pierda el foco, se vuelve a poner lo que traía por defecto la propiedad `Text`. Me funcionó al usar la propiedad `Tag`, lo utilicé como si fuese una propiedad `Text2`, en esa propiedad le dejé el mismo valor que tiene el `Text`, para que al perder el foco obtenga el valor del `Tag` y lo ponga en la propiedad `Text` y quede con el valor que traía por defecto. Lo que quiero saber es sí hago bien al utilizar la propiedad `Tag` como si fuese un atributo `Text2`, o si existe alguna otra propiedad que sea la indicada para utilizarla así.

Comment: No existe otra propiedad, lo que puedes hacer es crear un control de usuario (puedes heredar de TextBox) y agregar una propiedad que indica  el texto que se mostrará cuando el texto esté vacío y programar la lógica en el control de usuario.

Comment: Y cómo heredo de `textbox`?

Comment: public class MiTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox { ....

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearte tu `TextBox`personalizado como bien te indica Luis en su comentario y en él meter un nuevo campo Text2 o como quieras llamarlo. El código quedaría así :

```
public class TextBoxWith2Text : TextBox
{
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public TextBoxWith2Text()
    {
      //Lo que sea 
    }
    //Overrides o lo que necesites
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: No me ha quedado claro de cómo le agregaré el `text2`. Podrías por favor hacer un poco más completo el código para poder entenderlo.

Comment: En este ejemplo lo que hago es crear un `Textbox` personalizado que hereda del `TextBox` original y le añado el campo que te interesa. Bastaría con que tu diseño añadieses el tipo `TextBoxWith2Text` en lugar del `TextBox` original y lo podrías usar lo estabas haciendo hasta ahora, pero en lugar de usar la propiedad  `Tag` usa la nueva propiedad `Text2`. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

*¿Estas limitado a usar solo los controles de Windows Forms?* Porque [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) tiene un TextBox con esa funcionalidad.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/textboxext